# SQL Server - Table just 1 Identity Column - sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats says user_scans : 100%

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have one table made of just one identity column with is a PK clustered constraint on.

```
CREATE TABLE [Commodity].[tblUniqueIDIndex](
    [UniqueIDIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUniqueIDIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UniqueIDIndex] ASC
) ON [Commodity_FG]
) ON [Commodity_FG]
```

When I look at the index usage using `select * from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, SQL Server reports the following:

- user_seeks : 5 K
- user_scans: 34 Mln!

There are only 10 K records in the table.

This table is linked to other tables obviously where it is referenced as a Foreign Key. The other 'foreign tables' have several hundreds Mlns records in them each.

The software logic which performs statistical calculations treats each UniqueID as unique - there is no batch or grouping.

I am trying to understand **why SQL is scanning rather than seeking that table?**. Given the way this table is defined that makes no sense to me. Would anyone have an idea how this may happen or perhaps how to find why SQL server is not using the index?

Many thanks,
M

Comment: Can you search the plan cache for queries using the table and post details of any that are doing scans that are unexpected?

Comment: Many thanks for your great suggestion. I am looking at it using the SQL posted here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/27/digging-into-the-sql-plan-cache-finding-missing-indexes.aspx . You gave me a very good head start!

Comment: It would be hard to say without taking a deeper look into the query plans of the queries that cause the scans.

In general you would expect a seek on a small set of records. But for the query optimizer there is a tipping point where 'seeking' each individual reference would become more expensive than scanning the index. You must take the cost of the scan into account too. With a narrow index, lot's of records fit into a single page. Making a scan sometimes the cheaper option more quickly then expected. But like Martin Smith suggests, have a closer look at the queries causing the scans.

Comment: Several reasons: the table might just be **too small** for SQL Server's query optimizer to consider the overhead of doing a seek and then possibly an (expensive!) key lookup; or you're always requesting more columns than the index can provide, so it will need to use key lookups all the time - and avoids that by doing a scan rather than a seek